# Kill Command for pattern

Tags: php, linux

I have a process running as

```
php -q 1.php TEST 22
php -q 1.php MAIN 22
php -q 1.php TEST 222
php -q 1.php MAIN 222
php -q 2.php TEST 22
php -q 2.php MAIN 22
```

Can i create pattern using which i can create 1st two process only.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "pattern" in it?

Comment: Do you mean a shell script?

Answer (score 1):

I assume these are script command lines and you want to only kill the first two. For this, you should use the `pkill` command:

```
pkill -fx 'php -q 1.php * 22'
```

The `-f` option causes matching on the command line, and `-x` requires an exact match.

Comment: I think he wants the opposite: "i can create 1st two process only." What I understand is that he wants only the two first lines to run and not the rest. :-)